# Constructor Params throwing a "Can't resolve all parameters" error

Tags: angularjs, angular, dom, typescript

I tried looking through other questions but non of the solutions applied to my problem specifically.

about.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  Inject,
  ValueProvider 
  } from '@angular/core';

  /*const WINDOW_PROVIDER: ValueProvider = {
       provide: Window,
       useValue: window
     };*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('cubeArea') cubeArea: ElementRef;

constructor (@Inject('window') public window: Window) {

    return this;

}

public ngOnInit (): void {

    let cube: HTMLElement = (
        <HTMLElement>
            this
                .cubeArea
                .nativeElement
    ),

        self: AboutComponent = this;

    this
        .window
        .addEventListener(
            'mousemove',
            (
                ev: MouseEvent
            ): void => {

                cube
                    .style
                    .transform = 'rotateX(-'.concat(
                        ev.pageY.toString(),
                        'deg) rotateY(',
                        ev.pageX.toString(),
                        'deg)'
                    );

            });

     }

 }
```

I know my error is occurring in the constructor but I am not sure how to correct it. Weird thing is I got this to work without a problem running Angular QuickStart but I think I am missing dependencies using angular-cli here is what my app.module.ts file has.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Components

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

// Routes

import { routes } from './routers/app.router';


// Must export the config
export const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "stuff",
authDomain: "stuff",
databaseURL: "stuff",
storageBucket: "stuff"
};

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   RouterModule,
   routes,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
 declarations: [ 
   AppComponent,
   ContactComponent,
   PortfolioComponent,
   HeaderComponent,
   AboutComponent
 ],

'providers': [{

   'provide': Window,

   'useValue': window

 }],

 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can clone this Repository from https://github.com/ICEDBANK/Portfolio will remain public for a bit If you want an Idea on how to implement Firebase into your project good source code included.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't importing the `window`

try to include:

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  ValueProvider 
  } from '@angular/core';

const WINDOW_PROVIDER: ValueProvider = {
    provide: Window,
    useValue: window
};
```

at the top top of your script or in `app.module.ts`

**EDIT**

I thing what you're missing here is explicit declaration of `@Inject` in your component. So try:

```
constructor (@Inject('Window') window: Window) {...}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code above did not correct it. ={ In app.module.ts `'providers': [{

   'provide': Window,

   'useValue': window

 }],` should have gave me access to the window.

Comment: for that to work you've to initially import `Window` from somewhere

Comment: try using the constructor as `constructor (@Inject('Window') window: Window) {...}`

Comment: I made the changes to code above with current. I also added public window: Window "public" because system could not find **Property 'window' does not exist on type 'AboutComponent'.)** adding public got rid of that error but I am now getting **Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"** In console

Comment: `window` injection is case sensitive you've `@Inject('window')` I think it should be `@Inject('Window')`

Comment: This error has been a pain in the butt. I made the adjustment but I am still getting **"Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection""** [https://github.com/ICEDBANK/Portfolio] I pushed this project to here without my db info if you want to check it out feel free Thank you for your help so far